# Laravel get data from database that has one or multiple categories

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a filter and I had a little success but is not what I want.

The code is this :

```
public function scopeSearch( $query , $search )
    {
        if ( isset( $search['facility'] ) ) {
            $facilities = $search['facility'];
            $query->whereHas( 'facility' ,
                function ( $q ) use ( $facilities ) {
                    $q->where( 'facility_id' , $facilities );
                }
            );
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

The facilities variable is an array .

What it need to do is to return an apartment or more that has the facilities that I select(or the apartment that has more facilities but has the selected facilities too),but instead I get the apartment(s) with the facilities that have at least 1 facility that an apartment has .

What I need to do to return the apartments that have the selected facilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you may need to loop through the array using `foreach()` to ensure it has all members of the array:

```
        $facilities = $search['facility'];
        foreach( $facilities as $one_facilities ){
            $query->whereHas( 'facility' ,
                function ( $q ) use ( $one_facilities ) {
                    $q->where( 'facility_id' , $one_facilities );
                }
            );
        }
```

You may also need to use `orWhere()` if you want to match on just *some* facilities (i.e. return results that have 2 out of 3 facilities selected).

Comment: Thanks it works , but it loads very hard .Thanks again .